# Plot the confidence band with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, confidence-interval

I have a dataset that is similar to this :

```
x <- data.frame(date = c(20190902, 20190903, 20190904),
            Group = c(rep("A", 3)),
            mean = c(2.5, 3.4, 4.6),
            ci_upper = c(1.2, 0.5, 0.3),
            ci_lower = c(0.5, 0.4, 0.25))

y <- data.frame(date= c(20190902, 20190903, 20190904),
            Group = c(rep("B", 3)),
            mean = c(0.4, 3.8, 6.2),
            ci_upper = c(1.9, 0.9, 0.5),
            ci_lower = c(0.5, 0.8, 0.8))

df <- rbind(x, y)
```

I would like to plot the confidence band across the timeframe, with 2 different groups (A and B).

Currently I'm using this method but didn't work:

```
p <- ggplot(df) + 
    geom_line(aes(y = mean, x = date, group = type ))+
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = ci_lower, ymax = ci_upper, x = week, fill = "grey70"), alpha = 0.3)+
    scale_colour_manual("", values = "blue")+
    scale_fill_manual("", values = "grey12")
```

[image]

I wasn't sure how I can approach this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there. Only some small corrections of the `aes()` are needed.

But first I would slightly modify the input just to make the result looking prettier (now the `ci_upper`/`ci_lower` are not always more/less as compared with a corresponding mean value):

```
# to ensure reproducibility of the samples
set.seed(123)
df$ci_lower <- df$mean - sample(nrow(x))
df$ci_upper <- df$mean + sample(nrow(x))
```

The main thing which should be changed in your `ggplot()` call is definition of the aesthetics which will be used for plotting. Note, please, that default aesthetics values should be set only once.

```
p <- ggplot(df, 
    aes(x = as.Date(as.character(date), format = "%Y%m%d"), 
        y = mean,
        group = Group, col = Group, fill = Group)) + 
    geom_line() +
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = ci_lower, ymax = ci_upper), alpha = 0.3)+
    scale_colour_manual("", values = c("red", "blue")) +
    scale_fill_manual("", values = c("red", "blue"))
```

The result is as follows:

[image: plot_res]

Actually, the last two code rows are even not necessary, as the default ggplot-color scheme (which you have used to show the desired result) looks very nice, also.